# QtTest console application without x server

Tags: c++, qt, x11, qtcore, qttest

I have some unit tests for my project that I did with the QtTest framework. It is a console application, and actually I don't use anything from Qt apart from QtTest.

On my computer it works fine, however I am setting up continuous integration on Travis and I get :

```
lib_testapp: cannot connect to X server
```

I tried running my app with `-platform offscreen` as I saw on another thread but it doesn't seems to change anything.

There are these lines in the .pro :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG  += console c++11
QT      += testlib
```

My `main.cpp` looks like this :

```
class WatermarkingTests: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
void initTestCase() { }
void test1() { someTest(); }
void cleanupTestCase() { }
};

QTEST_MAIN(WatermarkingTests)
#include "main.moc"
```

`someTest()` is a purely mathematical function which makes some calls to `QVERIFY`.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work locally on your machine as opposed to the CI?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. But of course, I have a X server running, which I don't think is the case on Travis.

Comment: Well, you could try in VT of course instead of within your X server. Is it the full output? Can you provide a minimal test code? Also which qt version is this? Also, you should have `QT = core testlib` so that you do not get the gui added by default. Otherwise, it may link against the gui library.

Comment: Yes, if I run it from a VT in my computer it still works. (but only with -platform offscreen)

Comment: I don't use neither, it's a unit test (see edit in a few seconds)

Comment: The testlib does use qcoreapplication. Please show the test code, especially the main macro.

Comment: Ok didn't know ! And on my computer it's Qt5.2 however it's 4.8 on Travis. And yes this is the full output.

Comment: It seems it's only for Qt5 and Travis doesn't have it :(

Comment: I'll try to make my own main with QCoreApplication() instead then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the following line:

```
QTEST_MAIN(WatermarkingTests)
```

From the documentation:

> QTEST_MAIN ( TestClass )
>
> Implements a main() function that instantiates an application object and the TestClass, and executes all tests in the order they were defined. Use this macro to build stand-alone executables.
>
> If QT_GUI_LIB is defined, the application object will be a QApplication, otherwise it will be a QCoreApplication. If qmake is used and the configuration includes QT += gui, then QT_GUI_LIB will be defined automatically.

This means, you will get a QApplication rather than QCoreApplication since the `QT` variable contains core and gui by default. You would need to use the following statement to get around it:

```
QT = core testlib
```

Note that with Qt 5, you can just the following macro instead:

> [QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN( TestClass)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html#QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN)
>
> Implements a main() function that instantiates a QCoreApplication object and the TestClass, and executes all tests in the order they were defined. Use this macro to build stand-alone executables.
>
> Behaves like QTEST_MAIN(), but instantiates a QCoreApplication instead of the QApplication object. Use this macro if your test case doesn't need functionality offered by QApplication, but the event loop is still necessary.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 5.0.